# Как подключить VK PHP API?

Tags: vkontakte-api, api, вконтакте

Я не имею Composer и не собираюсь подключать Composer. Я хочу подключить VK PHP API без скачивания чего либо.

Comment: на «Stack Overflow на русском» вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке.

Comment: @TheNick регистрируешь приложение, получаешь токен-ключ, с помощью curl выполняешь запрос к серверам VK, и при успехе получаешь json, который самостоятельно обрабатываешь на своей стороне.При необходимости повторить.
Скачивать библиотеки - по желанию.